# How can i remove the black row appear in footer in the 1st page?

Tags: html, pdf

When I convert my html code in pdf view a black row appear in footer. How can I remove this?
[image: example]

Comment: please share the code that generated this, what you are trying to do and what did you try...

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: what method you use for converting it to PDF?